# Try to get data from table and insert into my database

Tags: php, html, forms

Can anyone help with this:

I am trying to collect email if the user likes a movie and update my database. I need two variables now: `email` and `id`. For `email`, I used a form to collect the user's email, but how do I collect the `id` without letting the user manually input that? For example, if the user submitted his/her email at the row of 101, how does the computer know that the id should be 101 and vice versa?

Here is what I got now for the table:

```
echo "<tr>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['id']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['name']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['rating']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['production']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['budget']."</td>
        <td>
            <form action='like.php' method='post'>
                E-mail: <input type='text' name='email3'><br>
                <input type='submit'>
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>";
```

The `like.php` is the place that will do the SQL. The table looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Ok, so what is your question, you dont actually ask one so I assume you want us to do the coding for you

Answer (score 0):

You can just let the user see a button and hide the other info, I also assume you only need an id as that should uniquely identify the user

```
echo "<tr>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['id']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['name']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['rating']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['production']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['budget']."</td>
        <td>
            <form action='like.php' method='post'>
                <input type='text' name='id' value=" . $value['id'] ."><br>
                <input type='submit' name="like" value="LIKE">
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>";
```

Now the `like.php` just reads the `id from the $_POST and uses it to maintain the like system.

You can also stop showing the user their id when you do this by removing this line

```
<td style='text-align:center'>".$value['id']."</td>
```

Alternatively, you should know which user is logged in, and that detail may be kept in the SESSION

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `hidden` input type. According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

> `<input>` elements of type hidden let web developers include data that
> cannot be seen or modified by users when a form is submitted. For
> example, the ID of the content that is currently being ordered or
> edited, or a unique security token. Hidden inputs are completely
> invisible in the rendered page, and there is no way to make it visible
> in the page's content.

Modify your code as below

```
echo "<tr>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['id']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['name']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['rating']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['production']."</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>".$value['budget']."</td>
        <td>
            <form action='like.php' method='post'>
                E-mail: <input type='text' name='email3'><br>
                <input type="hidden" value=". $value['id'] ." name"hidden_id">
                <input type='submit'>
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>";
```

Then you can access the `id` in your `like.php` as follows

```
$id = $_POST['hidden_id']
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helps.

Comment: @KarryXia You're welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please upvote and accept the answer if you [find this useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)